# Inner product using function in C

Tags: c, compilation

I tried to compute the inner product using function but the returned value is not correct.

```
/* Inner product x[n]*y[n]   */

#include <stdio.h>
#define n 5

void main()
{
    int i,sum;
    int x[n]={1,2,-1,3,5};
    int y[n]={0,6,-2,4,1};
    sum=inner_prod(x[n],y[n]);
    printf("\nThe inner product = %d",sum);
}

int inner_prod( int a[n], int b[n] )
{
    int i, s=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        s=s+b[i]*a[i];
    return (s);
}
```

Comment: You should edit this question to include your actual vs expected result. How can you tell the code is broken?

Comment: Not that it's relevant to the solution I think you should learn how to format your code properly. It'll be easier for you to read and people will be more eager to help you with it. Furthermore, it's very important when you are working with multiple people.

Comment: you are actually calling your routine `inner_product(x[5], y[5])`, this is, with the values of the _after to last_ value in each array respectively.  you have to call `inner_product(x, y)`, without specifying any subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passing of the array is improper as far as I know. You can simply do

in `main()`:

`sum = inner_prod(x, y)`

and in `inner_prod()` function:

```
int inner_prod(int *a, int *b)
{
    ....
}
```

Also, define this `inner_prod()` function above the `main()` function.

Comment: Thanks! this by using pointers, but what is the wrong in my program above without pointers!

Comment: Well, I just tried it on GeeksForGeeks IDE, and the answer it displayed  was 31.

Comment: Alright. There in the `main()` function, you are passing `x[n]`, which is not the array, but an element at 6th position of the array, which is meaningless, as the array size is only 5.

Comment: Without pointers, you can define the inner_prod() function as : `int inner_prod(int a[], int b[])`; as simple as that = )

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer if it was useful? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Thanks. All the Best to you from India.

Answer (score 6):

The dot product of the two vectors x,y in your case should result in 31 and would do so with your inner_prod function, but you calculated the dot product for x * x which in your case results in 40..

In short, isn't the problem that you just made a typo?

```
sum=inner_prod(x[n],x[n]);
```

I believe you wanted for this to have been the following?

```
sum=inner_prod(x,y);
```

Comment: After compiling I got "process axited after 5.15 seconds with return value 3221225477"

Comment: You should also be passing the number of elements in the array as a parameter so the function is relevant out of the context of this specific program.